# How to detect that an app is linked to Play Store or not?

Tags: google-play-store

Previously, Android Market didn't show `Uninstall` button for apps which aren't installed using it. So, this button was a nice identifier of linking status. Now, Play Store displays the button for every app.

Problem starts here: Titanium Backup started to show some of my purchased apps as unlinked from Play Store. It was unexpected.. Something had broke it. I could re-link apps using Titanium Backup, but I needed confirmation to avoid more problems. Well, I checked it using other apps like  App Manager of ROM Toolbox Pro. Interestingly, all such backup apps are displaying different linking status. So, I am screwed up.

I want to discover linking status without any help of third-party apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to https://play.google.com/store/account, with a regular desktop. Then click on the tab 'orders', you shall find there all the apps you downloaded via Google Play.

After clicking `Install` or `Installed` button, you'll get pop-up having device list. If app is already installed in a device with linked status, device would be inactive to send install signal. It can be used as identifier.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what `linked status` is. I'd downvote if I was capable of it.

Comment: How is it an answer? Read my question carefully..

Comment: I already know I have purchased/downloaded this app.. but, I don't know its linked with Market or not. That's the point..

Comment: Once an app is unlinked from Market, it becomes an app from external source. So, it doesn't receive updates from Market.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question right, but, if you open The Play Store (not on your phone's Store app, but on the web of any pc), Then you can click on any item of a list of your apps, and see its status on all of your devices (if you have more than one), it's to say, if it's not linked to google store, it'll appear as not installed, even if you have actually installed it trough the apk. See the image I just uploaded on the answer. If that's not what you want, sorry, I missunderstood you.

Comment: Thanks.. few months ago, web interface allowed me to install over device in which app was already installed. :) Now, its fine..

Comment: I have edited your answer to add last paragraph for clarification..